# mysql group concat improper ordering

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

I have a query which returns records in following order from db:

```
app_id  app_name    transaction_id  mobile_no   logtime_stamp          navigation_type   entered_code   display_text          User_Response
111     Unicef      1133           919552516853 10/5/2012 12:52:37 PM      0              Maharashtra   Student Attendance     2
111     Unicef      1133           919552516853 10/5/2012 12:52:37 PM      0              Pune          Student Attendance     2
111     Unicef      1133           919552516853 10/5/2012 12:52:37 PM      0              Baramati      Student Attendance     2
111     Unicef      1133           919552516853 10/5/2012 12:52:37 PM      0              Ravi School   Student Attendance     2
```

The query that returns the above records is an inner query.

I am doing a group_concat on these records to get a single row.

I am getting the following records:

```
app_name    transaction_id  mobile_no          entered_code                          display_text      User_Response
Unicef      1133            919552516853    Baramati,Ravi School,Maharashtra,Pune     Student Attendance        2
```

Now I dont understand on what basis is the `group_concat` function ordering the string - **Baramati,Ravi School,Maharashtra,Pune**!?

I want the ordering to be exactly the same as I am getting in the first set: 
**Maharashtra,Pune,Baramati,Ravi School**

As far as I know, a string in group_concat is sorted alphabetically by default. But the above result defies that.

Also I tried a sample query where in I am reading records from a table and group_concating that without assigning any specific order. The result had string sorted as per the insertion order. That is, the record that was inserted first came up first in the concat string and the last record as the last in the string.

So can I arrange/order my result set in the group_concat funcation based on the read order of the inner query?

Comment: Including the actual SQL would be helpful.

Comment: There is NO GUARANTEE that rows will be returned in any particular order absent an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 2):

Just looked at the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat
Found this line:

> To sort values in the result, use the ORDER BY clause.

as well as this, as an example:

```
 mysql> SELECT student_name,
     ->     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score
     ->               ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ')
     ->     FROM student
     ->     GROUP BY student_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
group_concat(entered_code order by entered_code)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will sort the records alphabetically which is not what I want in this case.

Comment: @DarkKnightFan What is the order you want? You can't expect to have it in the insertion order. You must explicitly ask for one determined order.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the full query and table data prior to the results you gave, it is difficult to tell of you can add an `ORDER BY` to you `GROUP_CONCAT()` however, it appears to be working fine in this demo:

```
select app_name,
  transaction_id,
  mobile_no,
  group_concat(entered_code),
  display_text,
  User_Response
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efe97/2).

Comment: well I know this works fine. I have mentioned this in the question also that when I am simply reading records from a table, it orders the records based on the insertion order. But in my case I am getting the records from multiple tables, forming a temp table of those records and then group-concating on that table. In that case, this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @DarkKnightFan there is no guarantee of the order of the data, unless you have the records in a specific order via an ID, etc

Answer (score 0):

As for documentation you have to be able to order group concat result based on some field or expression. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

You should not rely on an "insertion order" at all since there is no such feature in MySQL. In most case you see data in this order, but it is not being ordered actually and later you go less relevant this order will become.